# Plotting the Impulsefunction

Tags: matlab

so I'm new to Matlab and had to draw the Impulsefunction with y(n) is only 1 if n == 3, else 0. The following code works:

```
n = -5:5;                       
f = n;                          % allocate f
for i = 1 : length(n)           
    f(i) = dd1(n(i)-3);         
end                            

stem(n, f);                     
function y = dd1(n)            
    y = 0;                    
    if n == 0                
        y = 1;              
    end
end
```

But I feel like it's to complicated, so I tried the following:

```
n = -5:5
stem(n, fo)
function y = fo(n)
    y = 0
    if n == 3
        y=1
    end
end
```

This returns

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in alternative>fo (line 5)
    if n == 3

Error in alternative (line 2)
stem(n, fo)
```

I feel like I'm missing something trivial here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` is no vector-wise operation but expects a single boolean (or at least a scalar that it can cast to a boolean).

But you can do this vector-wise:

```
lg = n == 3;
```

This produces a logical (MATLAB's name for boolean) array (because `n` is an array and not a vector), which is true where `n` is equal (`==`) to three. So you don't need a function, because you can make use of MATLAB's ability to work with vectors and arrays implicitly.
(for your code it would be `f = (n-3) == 3`)

A last hint: if you have a state-space system (`ss`-object), you can use the function `step` to get the step-response as a plot.

Comment: but the first solution worked fine, what is the difference to the second approach?

Comment: 1) that you call the function `fo(n)` without an input argument (that is what MATLAB) complains about 2) that `if n == 3` does not work for an array because it returns also an array. In fact, it will return `-0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0` if you would call `fo(n)`...(this is the error that is not raised yet because MATLAB didn't even come so far due to 1))